# seekp/g and tellp/g does not work properly

Tags: c++, io, fstream, iostream, getline

Whenever I try to use `tellp/g` and `seekp/g`functions on `fstream` object, and use the `fstream::getline(cstr, bufsize)` function, it just don't work properly and don't store anything in 'cstr' variable. and it does not report any problem which invalidate the stream like `failbit` or `badbit`

Sample code: what it does is read it line by line and on each read it jumps to the end of the file and print the next line's offset from the beginning of the file.

```
    int main()
    {

      // Prepare file
      fstream f("test.txt", fstream::ate | fstream::in | fstream::out);

      // Prepare needed data for production
      auto end_mark = f.tellg();
      size_t count{0};
      char c[64];

      // Go back to the beginning 
      f.seekg(0, fstream::beg);

      while(f && f.tellg() != end_mark && f.getline(c, 64))
        {
          count += f.gcount();

          auto mark = f.tellg();
          // Go to the end
          f.seekp(0, fstream::end);

          f << count; // print the next line's offset
          if(mark != end_mark) f << " ";

          // print results on shell ..For debug purposes
          cout << c << " - " << count << endl;

          // Go back to the last read point
          f.seekp(mark);
        }
      return 1;
    }
```

test.txt:

```
    abcd
    efg
    hi
    j
```

test.txt after execution:

```
    abcd
    efg
    hi
    j
    5 6 7 8
```

But what was expected is:

```
    abcd
    efg
    hi
    j
    5 9 12 14
```

And the output from the shell is:

```
    abcd - 5
     - 6
     - 7
     - 8
```

**Notice that there is nothing stored in the c variable**

But what was expected from the shell is:

```
    abcd - 5
    efg - 9
    hi - 12
    j - 14
```

**I want to point out that** it's only the `tellp/g()` and `seekp/g()` functions that misses the `fstream::getline()` function. Using the following code:

```
    int main()
    {
      // Prepare file
      fstream f("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);

      size_t count{0};
      char c[64];

      while(f && f.getline(c, 64))
        {
          count += f.gcount();

          // print results on shell ..For debug purposes
          cout << c << " - " << count << endl;
        }
      return 1;
    }
```

**Notice: the `tellp/g()` and `seekp/g()` functions are stripped out**

The shell outputs the following:

```
    abcd - 5
    efj - 9
    hi - 12
    j - 14
```

Can someone tell me why it behaves like this, And please I'm trying to understand this weird behavior 
I'm compiling with GCC-6.3.0-1
If there is any extra detail you want let me know

#### EDIT:

I've updated my compiler to GCC-8.2.0-3 and compiled normally and with -std=c++11/14/17 options but, still facing the same problem...
Any suggestions will be super appreciated

Comment: Forgot to mention, I've read somewhere that it might be a compiler error in gcc. I'm using g++ 6.3.0-1

Comment: It is never a compiler error. They happen but are so rare nowadays that when they do happen people get excited.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line: `f << count;`?

Comment: @KorelK He is creating an index of the file and placing this index at the end of the file. So the line `f << count` writes the index of the line at the end of the file.

Comment: Works for me. What version of g++ are you using. More importantly what version of the standard library are you using?

Comment: So the code looks good and works with my compiler. So there seems to be an issue with a standard stream library.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `f << count` with `f << mark`

Comment: Is the count same as the mark? @MartinYork
I tried now but it outputs : 9 13 16 18

Comment: @MartinYork  I've added a line of code to output the "c" and "count" variables

Comment: Unrelated: Don't forget that on some systems the end of line is multiple characters.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah but here it's only a char '\n' it's not an array

Comment: I tested on my linux pc, everything is fine! I tested on wandbox from 4.x.x to 9.2 and also on every compiler everything works as expected. Hint: have you some obscure local settings? So please set LANG= and all the other related things to english. Maybe you have some nonprintable chars in your source or textfile? check that `file <x.cpp> gives you ascii, same for test.txt. And yes, sounds stupied, but: Have you really compiled your code again? Maybe some object files are hanging around? So please delete them all and rebuild with the selected compiler.

Comment: @Klaus There is no nonprintable chars in the file it's exactly identical if not, it would have toggled the fail bit, and I've compiled for sure my friend. And about the object file, there is no object files generated it's just one single `main.cpp` file